# Compare dates and filter rows within a group with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

**Sample DF:**

```
ID   Name        Price     Date             Fit_Test
1    Apple         10      2018-01-15          Super_Fit
2    Apple         10      2018-01-15          Super_Fit
3    Apple         10      2019-01-15          Super_Fit

4    Orange        12      2019-02-15          Not_Fit
5    Orange        12      2018-09-25          Not_Fit
6    Orange        12      NaT                 Not_Fit
7    Orange        12      2028-01-25          Not_Fit

8    Banana        15      2019-12-25          Medium_Fit
9    Banana        15      NaT                 Medium_Fit

10   Cherry         30     2021-06-23          Super_Fit

11   PineAp         30     2023-02-03          Medium_Fit
12   PineAp         30     2020-12-13          Medium_Fit
```

**Expected DF:**

```
ID   Name        Price     Date             Fit_Test
1    Apple         10      2018-01-15          Super_Fit
2    Apple         10      2018-01-15          Super_Fit
3    Apple         10      2019-01-15          Super_Fit

7    Orange        12      2028-01-25          Not_Fit

8    Banana        15      2019-12-25          Medium_Fit
9    Banana        15      NaT                 Medium_Fit

10   Cherry         30     2021-06-23          Super_Fit

11   PineAp         30     2023-02-03          Medium_Fit
```

**Problem Statement:**

I want to `group-by` by `Name` and `Price` and then filter based on `Date` with `Fit_Test` as conditional column.

1. If Fit_Test is `Super_Fit` then don't the no operation is needed. **(Rows 1,2,3 and 10 is same in Input and Expected DF)**
2. If within a `Name` and `Price` conditions and Fit_Test is not `Super_Fit` and there is no `NaT` in that group then compare the dates, whichever has the **highest date keep it**  **(ID 11&12 and in Expected 12 is deleted)**
3. If within a `Name` and `Price` conditions and Fit_Test is not `Super_Fit` and there is a `NaT` in that group:

   3.1 If the count in that group is greater than 2, then compare the dates, whichever has the **highest date keep it**  **(ID 4,5,6,7 and in Expected 4,5,6 is deleted)**

   3.2 If the count in that group is equal to 2, then keep both the rows  ** 
    (ID 8,9 and in Expected 8,9 is there)**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where you get stuck?

Comment: I am not able to write queries to chain these conditions. For Point 1, I have `m1 = df['Fit_Test'].eq('Super_Fit').groupby([df['Name'],df['Price']]).transform('all')`. I want similar queries for Point 2 &3 so I can chain them

Comment: I don't think there is a straight forward way to do this, filter each condition from main df and concat result once, would be my choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

m1 = df['Fit_Test'].eq('Super_Fit').groupby([df['Name'],df['Price']]).transform('all')

m2 = df['Date'].notna().groupby([df['Name'],df['Price']]).transform('all')

m22 = df['Date'].eq(df.groupby(['Name', 'Price'])['Date'].transform('max'))

m3 = df.groupby(['Name', 'Price'])['Date'].transform('size').eq(2)

df = df[m1 | (m2 & m22) | (~m2 & m3) | (~m2 & m22)]
#it seems conditions should be simplify
#df = df[m1 | m22 | (~m2 & m3)]
print (df)
    ID    Name  Price       Date    Fit_Test
0    1   Apple     10 2018-01-15   Super_Fit
1    2   Apple     10 2018-01-15   Super_Fit
2    3   Apple     10 2019-01-15   Super_Fit
6    7  Orange     12 2028-01-25     Not_Fit
7    8  Banana     15 2019-12-25  Medium_Fit
8    9  Banana     15        NaT  Medium_Fit
9   10  Cherry     30 2021-06-23   Super_Fit
10  11  PineAp     30 2023-02-03  Medium_Fit
```

Comment: Getting this warning `FutureWarning: In the future, 'NAT == x' and 'x == NAT' will always be False.` for `m22`

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - what is your pandas version?

Comment: 0.23.0 ,my pandas version

Comment: @RahulAgarwal - for me it working correctly in pandas 0.24.2

Comment: Need some further help in this..can you help!!

Comment: Sure, what is problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190440/discussion-between-rahul-agarwal-and-jezrael).